# R: Adding static lines in animation (GGAnimate)

Tags: r, animation, gganimate

I am trying to run an animation - plotting a line (geom_line) in R. My data is as follows:

```
  Date      BookToPrice   NumStk
   <yearmon>       <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 Dec 1989         -1   0.00442 
 2 Dec 1989         -0.9 0.000492
 3 Dec 1989         -0.8 0.000492
 4 Dec 1989         -0.7 0       
 5 Dec 1989         -0.6 0       
 6 Dec 1989         -0.5 0       
 7 Dec 1989         -0.4 0.000492
 8 Dec 1989         -0.3 0.000492
 9 Dec 1989         -0.2 0.000492
10 Dec 1989         -0.1 0
```

I am plotting geom_line using the following code sequence:

```
q<-ggplot(data = data.pb, mapping = aes(x = BookToPrice, y = NumStk)) +
  
  geom_line(size = 1.5) +

  transition_states(Date, transition_length = 4, state_length = 1) +
  
  view_follow(fixed_x = TRUE, fixed_y = TRUE) +

  labs(title = 'Distribution through time : {closest_state}')
## use current_frame if using transition_manual


animate(plot = q, 
        nframes=length(unique(data.pb$Date)),
        detail = 2,
        fps = 2,
        width = 1200,
        height = 1000,
        end_pause = 8,
        renderer = gifski_renderer("anim.gif"))
```

Everything works perfectly well, no issues with the code here.

What I want to do is to add a few static lines... so say the distribution of date x is plotted - I want to leave that as a reference on the graph. Then for date y and so on...

Is it possible to combine multiple geom_line charts, but run the animation on a singular chart?

I tried adding a secondary line just to check whether I can add the line or not, but it gives me just a singular frame and just warnings on processing.

So:

1. How do I add a static line to the animation?
2. The static line appears when the animation has processed a certain date...

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a workaround (and it's a horrible one). I created an additional timeseries with the same date and a value of 0 before the date I want the plot to appear, and static values post. This shows the plot - in a static fashion - but does not look nice.

If I find a proper answer, will come back here and add.